# Can SQL columns update automatically based on criteria in other tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an excel workbook that I would like to implement in SQL.

The workbook has three sheets:

- Sheet 1 is Options
- Sheet 2 is Data
- Sheet 3 is Results

In Excel, the results sheet performs an index match with three criteria and returns values (matches) from the data sheet. Two of the three criteria are on the options sheet, the other on the results sheet.

1) Can SQL columns update based on criteria in other tables and can it do it automatically as the values in the other tables change?

2) Can SQL match data across multiple columns so that results look like the data below.

Hopefully the Dummy Data below helps explain things.

[image: Dummy Data Image]

Thanks

Karen

Comment: You seem to want a view or just a simple select statement.

Comment: you can use triggers

Comment: The results seems to be a simple inner join on two fields.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Sometimes we get kind of aggressive on closing questions. To answer *your* question:  In SQL you typically keep your raw data (your input data) in tables.  Then, when you need to see your results, you run SQL queries to generate them. This is *slightly* different from Excel, because that program gives you the illusion your results tabs are *live*.  You would have tables called `options` and `data`. This is important: you ordinarily don't keep your results (the stuff derived from your data) in tables of their own, but rather regenerate them as needed.

Comment: Thanks Everyone! Karen

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1) **Yes**. In order to do so, you should use a trigger (or in other words, stored procedure in database which is automatically called when an event happen - in your case on values change).

2) From what I see - this is a result of JOIN query between two tables, so again **Yes**.
For more information, please provide SQL structure.

Comment: Thanks Kamil-kubichi. Now that I know it's doable I'll read up on both triggers and JOINS.  Thanks! karen